# PHP doesnt render pages

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-http-server

PHP doesn't render pages in Ubuntu 11.10

Installed apache/PHP using

```
sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2
```

my file (info.php):

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
    echo "test";
?>
```

opens in browser, but shows a blank white page.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the logs? `/var/log/apache2/` is where they're located. PHP should be printing any errors into the error log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to enable PHP5 module in Apache. Guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

```
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @Kazzy If this worked for you, you should indicate such by clicking the outlined checkmark on the left-hand side of the question. This allows others to quickly see that the question was answered. Welcome to [su]!

Answer (score -2):

Confirm if your server is running.

You can do that by typing localhost or the loopback address in your safari (127.0.0.1).